# Sending marketing parameters to the mobile application via a link

Tags: analytics, tracking, mobile-application, firebase-dynamic-links, utm

What’s the best way to pass parameters like utm and custom variables?
I am talking about a situation where the ad links directly to the mobile application and I care about maintaining these parameters in the application.
So that I can use these variables when firing analytical tags.

I used to use Firebase and the Dynamic Links functionality, but from what I remember there was only the option to send utms.
It is not possible to configure additional parameters.
 
What would be the best solution for this purpose?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.